# getting error "Subscript out of range error" in asp classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am writing code for string search in classic asp but it show error.
For example if is write in search

```
my name is lucky from earth
```

I get this error

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'
>   Subscript out of range: '6'
>   /bdn6/prod_search.asp, line 68

where **line 68** is :

```
SWord = SWord & " " &  Trim(arrKeyWords(j))
```

my code is as below given:

```
<%
Dim SearchWord, arrKeyWords, arrQry, MainQty, FinalQty, MergeQry, WhereCon, Cnt, tsearch, i, j
SearchWord = trim(request("searcha"))
arrKeyWords = Split(SearchWord ," ") 
Cnt = Ubound(arrKeyWords) + 1
%>

<%
dim Qry, SWord, NLWord, TableName, LastIndex
MainQty = "select a.rProd_name, r_id "
TableName = "from reseller_prod a, brand e, V_brand f, V_modal g Where a.rprod_vbrand=f.Vb_Id and f.vb_active=0 and a.rprod_vmodel=g.Vm_id and g.Vm_active=0 and a.rProd_brand=e.Brand_id and e.brand_active=0 and a.rProd_price <> 0 and a.rProd_price is not Null and a.rprod_nowallowd=0 and a.r_id in(select s_usrid from Reseller where S_approval=0) and a.r_id in(select usr_id from usr where Usr_Active=0)"
NLWord = ""
For i = 0 To Cnt
SWord = ""
For j = 0 To ((Cnt) - i)

SWord = SWord & " " &  Trim(arrKeyWords(j))  'getting error on this line: Subscript out of range

Next
WhereCon = WhereCon & " And (a.rProd_name like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%' or f.vb_name like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%' or g.Vm_modal like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%')"
Qry = MainQty & ", " & (i + 1) & " as SortRecord " & TableName & " " & WhereCon
LastIndex = i + 1
Qry = Qry & NLWord
NLWord = NLWord & " And (a.rProd_name not like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%' And  f.vb_name not like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%' And g.Vm_modal not like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%')"
FinalQty = FinalQty & Qry & " UNION "   

WhereCon = ""
Qry = ""

Next

FinalQty = left(FinalQty, (Len(FinalQty) - 6))

MergeQry = FinalQty
FinalQty = ""

 MainQty = "select a.Prod_name, '' as r_id "
 TableName = "from product a, brand e, V_brand f, V_modal g Where a.prod_vbrand=f.Vb_Id and f.vb_active=0 and a.prod_vmodel=g.Vm_id and g.Vm_active=0 and a.Prod_brand=e.Brand_id and e.brand_active=0 and a.prod_active=0 and a.Prod_price <> 0 and a.Prod_price is not Null"

 NLWord = ""
 For i = 0 To Cnt

 SWord = ""
 For j = 0 To ((Cnt) - i)

 SWord = SWord & " " &  Trim(arrKeyWords(j))
 Next
WhereCon = WhereCon & " And (a.Prod_name like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%' or a.prod_keyword like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%' or f.vb_name like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%' or g.Vm_modal like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%')"
Qry = MainQty & ", " & (LastIndex + i + 1) & " as SortRecord " & TableName & " " & WhereCon
Qry = Qry & NLWord
NLWord = NLWord & " And (a.Prod_name not like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%' and a.prod_keyword not like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%' And f.vb_name not like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%' And g.Vm_modal not like '%" & Trim(SWord) & "%')"
FinalQty = FinalQty & Qry & " UNION "   

 WhereCon = ""
Qry = ""

Next
FinalQty = left(FinalQty, (Len(FinalQty) - 6))
FinalQty = FinalQty & "Order By SortRecord"

MergeQry = MergeQry & " UNION " & FinalQty

response.Write(MergeQry)
 %>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Read something about [Array Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz(v=vs.84).aspx):

> ```
> Dim A(10)
> ```
>
> Although the number shown in the parentheses is `10`, all **arrays in
>   VBScript are zero-based**, so this array actually contains `11`
>   elements. In a zero-based array, the number of array elements is
>   always the number shown in parentheses plus one. This kind of array is
>   called a fixed-size array.

[**Split Function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5(v=vs.84).aspx)

> Returns a **zero-based, one-dimensional array** containing a specified
>   number of substrings.

[**UBound Function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhx59d0t(v=vs.84).aspx)

> Returns the **largest available subscript** for the indicated dimension of
>   an array.

Therefore, use either

```
Cnt = Ubound(arrKeyWords)  ''' instead of Cnt = Ubound(arrKeyWords) + 1
```

or (insisting upon `Cnt = Ubound(arrKeyWords) + 1`)

```
For i = 0 To Ubound(arrKeyWords)
    SWord = ""
    For j = 0 To (Ubound(arrKeyWords) - i)
        SWord = SWord & " " &  Trim(arrKeyWords(j))
    Next
    ''' … '''
Next
```

or (insisting upon `Cnt = Ubound(arrKeyWords) + 1`)

```
For i = 0 To cnt -1
    SWord = ""
    For j = 0 To (cnt - 1 - i)
        SWord = SWord & " " &  Trim(arrKeyWords(j))
    Next
    ''' … '''
Next
```